# Pytest- use a generator for mark.parametrize

Tags: python, mongodb, testing, automated-tests, pytest

I have a mongo db with a very large collection that I need to run tests on with Pytest.
I am trying to do it the usual route of using the mark.parametrize dectorator but with pymongo.cursor Cursor object:

```
def get_all_data():
    return db["collection"].find({}) # query to retrieve all documents from the collection

@pytest.mark.parametrize("doc", get_all_data())
def test_1(doc):
    assert doc["val"] == 1
    ....
```

The problem with this code is pytest in the collection stage before running tests automatically converts the generator into a list. I don't want this because of 2 reasons:

1. This is very slow due to the fact the collection is very large.
2. Stack overflow- Not enough RAM to load all of this data anyway.

Meaning I cannot use mark.parametrize, however how can I still use a generator to run tests 1 at a time and not to load everything immediately into memory? Is it even possible with Pytest?

Comment: it is not, during the collection phase pytest must know all of the tests that are to be run before continuing onwards

Comment: If so, are there other tools I can use to test very large datasets? (much larger than my RAM)

Comment: at that point are you actually writing _tests_?

Comment: Yes. I am using millions of documents to test if an algorithmic component is working properly

Comment: how can you possibly know if it's correct if there's millions of inputs

Comment: I do regression testing, so the new version is always compared either to a previous one or a golden standard one. This creates a situation where my database is populated by varying vectors from all the stable release versions.

Comment: you're not really running "tests" at that point but an integration pipeline -- for which a unit testing tool (such as pytest) is not going to be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of this workaround - write a fixture to pass the generator to a single test. Then `check` each entry individually in the same test using [`pytest-check`](https://github.com/okken/pytest-check) (because i guess you need to `assert` each entry separately and continue even if some entries fail).

```py
@pytest.fixture
def get_all_data():
    yield db["collection"].find({})

def test_1(get_all_data):
    for each in get_all_data:
        check.is_(each["val"], 1)
```

Comment: Maybe you could add `check` fixture into the test function signature (`def test_1(get_all_data, check)`) so that it's clear where it comes from.

Comment: Yeah that's true for fixtures in general. Pytest does a lot of magic.. For `check` though, it's an import from `pytest_check`